# How to prove an asymptotic formula for the number of distinct prime factors of an integer?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Let $\omega(n)$ be  the number of distinct prime factors of an integer $n$. I need to show that the sum $\sum_{x\le n}\omega(x)$ is 
$$n\log\log n+bn+O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$$ 
Any solutions or link to existing solutions to this problem is most welcome.

Comment: I'm guessing that you want the sum from $1$ to $n$ of $\omega(j),$ where $\omega(j)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $j.$ Otherwise it cannot be this big (larger than $n$). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem

Comment: Yep, Hardy and Wright, Theorem 430.

Comment: Also posted to (and answered on) MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180117/how-to-prove-an-asymptotic-formula-for-the-number-of-distinct-prime-factors-of-a

Comment: "Chameleon" questions are strongly discouraged: they break the link between questions and answers. I edited the question to match the answer that it received. If you also want to ask another question, go ahead and do it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the logic of H&W the sum in question is
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n \leq x}\omega(n) = \sum_{n \leq x}\sum_{p \mid n}1
\end{equation}
by definition of $\omega(n)$, Switching the order of summation gives
\begin{equation}
\sum_{p \leq x} \sum_{\substack{n \leq x \\ p \mid n}} 1
\end{equation}

It shouldn't be too hard to see that the inner sum, being the number of multiples of $p$ which are no greater than $x$ is simply $[x/p]$ (where the square brackets represent the integer part).

We can get rid of the square brackets at the cost of an error of size $O(1)$ (actually the error will either be $0$ or $1$ but this is a nicer cover-all). Therefore our sum is
\begin{equation}
\sum_{p \leq x}\left(\frac{x}{p} + O(1)\right) = x\sum_{p \leq x}1 + O(\pi(x))
\end{equation}
and the result follows from Mertens theorem which states
\begin{equation}
\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p} = \log \log x + B_1 + O\left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: Note that after Stijn posted this answer, OP completely changed the question.